# MPI - MPI_Probe does not block and receives same message

Tags: c, mpi

So, somehow MPI_Probe receives the same message even though it is only sent once.
I execute the program with only 2 process of which process 1 is sending two messages, one two retrieve a task and another one to send the result. I send the messages with different tags to differentiate those two.

So what's supposed to happen is following:

1. Process 0 waits for a task request
2. Process 1 sends a task request indicated by tag=0
3. Process 0 sends the task
4. Process 1 does the task and sends the results back to process 0 indicated by tag=1.

   -- This is the part where the first problem occurs: Process 0 still receives tag=0
      shown by the printf
5. Process 0 receives the task enters the else-if-block where tag==1 
   -- It does not.
6. Process 1 breaks the while loop - DEBUGGING PURPOSE
7. Procces 0 is supposed to be blocked by MPI_Probe but is not, instead it continues to
   run and always shows that the received Tag is still 0

The code is still messy and inefficient. I just want a minimal working program to build upon and to optimize. But still any tip is appreciated!

The code:

```
if(rank == 0) {

        struct stack* idle_stack = init_stack(env_size-1); 
        struct sudoku_stack* sudoku_stack_ptr = init_sudoku_stack(256); 
        push_sudoku(sudoku_stack_ptr, sudoku);


        int it=0;
        while(1) {
            printf("ITERATION %d\n", it);
            
            int idle_stack_size = stack_size(idle_stack);
            int _sudoku_stack_empty = sudoku_stack_empty(sudoku_stack_ptr);

            MPI_Probe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            printf("TAG: %d\n", status.MPI_TAG);

            // So this part is supposed to be entered once
            if(status.MPI_TAG == 0) {
                
                if(!sudoku_stack_empty(sudoku_stack_ptr)) {
                    printf("SENDING TASK\n");
                    int *next_sudoku = pop_sudoku(sudoku_stack_ptr);
                    MPI_Send(next_sudoku, v_size, MPI_INT, status.MPI_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                } else {
                    // But since the Tag stays 0, it is called multiple times until
                    // a stack overflow occurs
                    printf("PUSHING TO IDLE STACK\n");
                    push(idle_stack, status.MPI_SOURCE); 
                }

            } else if(status.MPI_TAG == 1) {
                // This part should actually be entered by the second received message
                printf("RECEIVING SOLUTION\n");
                int count;
                MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_INT, &count);
                int* recv_sudokus = (int*)malloc(count * sizeof(int));
                MPI_Recv(recv_sudokus, count, MPI_INT, status.MPI_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                for(int i = 0; i < count; i+=v_size) {
                    printf("%d ", recv_sudokus[i]);
                    if((i+1) % m_size == 0){
                        printf("\n");
                    }
                }
                
                // DEBUG - EXIT PROGRAM
                teardown(sudoku_stack_ptr, idle_stack);
                break;

                push_sudoku(sudoku_stack_ptr, recv_sudokus);
            } else if(status.MPI_TAG == 2) {
                //int* solved_sudoku = (int*)malloc(v_size * sizeof(int));
                //MPI_Recv(solved_sudoku, v_size, MPI_INT, status.MPI_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                //TODO
            }
            

            it++;
        }


    } else {
        int* sudoku = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*v_size);
        int* possible_sudokus = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*m_size*v_size);  

        while(1) {
            // Send task request
            printf("REQUESTING TASK\n");
            int i = 0;
            MPI_Send(&i, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            // Wait for and receive task
            printf("RECEIVING TASK\n");
            MPI_Recv(sudoku, v_size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

            printf("CALCULATING\n");
            int index = 0;
            for(int i = 1; i <= m_size; i++) {
                int is_safe_res = is_safe_first_empty_cell(sudoku, i);
                if(is_safe_res) {
                    int* sudoku_cp = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*v_size);
                    memcpy(sudoku_cp, sudoku, sizeof(int)*v_size);
                    insert_to_first_empty_cell(sudoku_cp, i);
                    memcpy(&possible_sudokus[index], sudoku_cp, sizeof(int)*v_size);
                    index+=v_size;
                    free(sudoku_cp);
                }
            }

            printf("SENDING\n");
            MPI_Send(possible_sudokus, index*v_size, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            break;
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: If probe tells you there is a message, you should issue a receive to receive it. However, one of the actions after a probe is `f(status.MPI_TAG == 0) {` which only does a send. I don't understand this "if there is an incoming message, send a message".

Comment: Thank you very much! Calling MPI_Recv solved the issue. The idea behind it is, that the process with rank 0 assigns tasks to every other process. So some process is finished with it's task and sends a message to process 0 to get a new task.